# Is there a openid-selector that supports Facebook, Twitter, and top sites in the 2010's?

Tags: openid

Here is OpenID-selector as implemented from http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/

[image]
It works great except for the fact most people on earth only recognize the first two buttons.

Is there an openid selector helper that includes endpoints for some sites people actually use? (Facebook, Twitter, QQ, Weibo, Amazon)

Yes, I'll roll my own. But looking for a supported solution first.

Comment: It looks like OpenID is dead. I don't see much of anything on the web about it since 2009.

Comment: Maybe Facebook and Twitter are not listed because they don't run an OpenID provider.

Comment: I see, it looks like everyone is now putting up with proprietary federated logins. Open was fun while it lasted.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned the sites you mentioned don't use OpenID. They use OAuth instead.

On Wikipedia is [a description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OpenID_vs._pseudo-authentication_using_OAuth) on how both of those differ.

And if you look closely: The openID selector that you mentioned [is capable to handle this](https://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/issues/detail?id=31).

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/450534/Implement-Facebook-login-with-OpenID-Selector) is a HOWTO to use Facebook with openID selector.

Additionally there is that comment in the FAQ:

> Comment by project member andriy.gerasika, Oct 19, 2010
>
> [..]
>
> I will make a HOWTO in v1.3 about how to plug-in Facebook support

Maybe you can carefully remind andriy about his post there.

Answer (score 1):

None of the sites listed can be used to log into OpenId. There are web sites out there that let you quickly log in to their site using Facebook, Twitter, etc., but those are using OAuth, rather than OpenId, and that works differently than OpenId -- OAuth gives a web site access to info from your Facebook, Twitter, etc. account without providing your login info, whereas OpenId is used to actually use the same account multiple places.

Here's a link to info as to what sites still do use OpenId: http://openid.net/get-an-openid/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to have "open" solution in the sense of OpenID or open source then supported solution that supports selectors people really use that can provide you necessary widgets and other web services can be subscribed from

→ [Janrain](http://janrain.com/product/social-login/) ←

The developer side (your view) is documented [here](http://developers.janrain.com/).

Besides the social login they provide more services. If you have some budget to spend then this seems to be supported, tuned, bug-less way to go.

I'm currently evaluating their services as an option for my project.

BTW: Their [about](http://janrain.com/about/) pages says

> ...In late 2004, Founder Larry Drebes and a few engineers began working closely with the early proponents of the OpenID protocol to provide a simple way for companies to solve this problem. Their work laid the foundation for Janrain and what is known today as social login...